# How to find the longest repeated substring of given string

Tags: java, string

I am new java and I was given assignment to find the longest substring of a string. 
I research online and seems that good way of approaching this problem will be implementing suffix tree. 
Please let me know how I can do this or if you have any other solutions. keep in mind this is suppose to be done with low level of java knowledge.

Thanks in adavance.

P.S. the tester string is  reassuring.

```
    /**
This method will find the longest substring of a given string.
String given here is reassuring. 

 */
public String longestRepeatedSubstring()
{
    String longestRepeatedSubstring = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++ )
    {
        String one = text.substring(0,i); 

        for(int o = 0; o<text.length();o++)
        {
            Sting two = text.substring(0,o);
            if(one.equals(two))
            {
                longestRepeatedSubstring = one;
            }

        }

    }
    return longestRepeatedSubstring; 
}
```

Comment: I have just research and was hoping that to find a alternative solution.

Comment: I was thinking about using two for loop and than one loop will get various substring of a string and another loop will see if it find copy of that in rest of the string.

Comment: i am not asking  for solution. i was asking for a better idea of approaching this since suffix tree look higher level of java programming

Comment: @DfsdfsdfDsfsdfdsf show us what you have tried so far.. so that we can help you out :)

Comment: A few for-loops to try every possible substring would do it, or even a regular expression. It won't be the most efficient solution but it'll be fine for short strings.

Comment: please check my code this is what i have tried

Comment: What do you mean with the longest substring of a string?.  So if you have "reassuring" the longest substring is "reassurin" or "eassuring". This is always a string with the length of the original string minus one, or what do you mean? I don't really get your question...

Comment: The longest repeating substring of "reassuring" is "s"

Comment: a minimum of research on google would have uncovered dozens of algorithms about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you debug your code you will see that you the code isn't doing what you think.  AFAIK you need at least three loops and you can't assume you would only start from the first character.  Here is one possible solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String longest = longestDuplicate("ababcaabcabcaab");
    System.out.println(longest);
}

public static String longestDuplicate(String text) {
    String longest = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 2 * longest.length() * 2; i++) {
        OUTER:
        for (int j = longest.length() + 1; j * 2 < text.length() - i; j++) {
            String find = text.substring(i, i + j);
            for (int k = i + j; k <= text.length() - j; k++) {
                if (text.substring(k, k + j).equals(find)) {
                    longest = find;
                    continue OUTER;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

prints

```
abcaab
```

for "reassuring" it prints `r` not `s` which was my first guess. ;)

Comment: For "qwqwabcabc" returns "qw" instead of "abc"

Comment: what is OUTER: ? is that a java concept? I understand what it is doing but can't understand what topic it will be

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal it's a label for the loop which allows you to continue an outer loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know its old post. But I think it can be done with two loops(brute force algo) also where for every character , run inner loop with index greater than outer loop. If matched just compare each character sequentially( with `++` operator till we get match) till it is positive. I know its high level algo, will implement once get time :). Just a thought popped up.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I just tested the code. It really doesn't work with some other cases. I think it might find the *first* duplicate or something. Here is a test case run against the code: "aaxaabcccxccc" -- I believe the longest  dupe would be "ccc" but instead it returns "aa". Where is the current longest being compared against a subsequently found longest?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "testingString";
        char[] strArr = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder bm = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isPresent = false;
        int len = strArr.length;
        int initial =0;
        int dinitial=0;

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        HashMap<String, String> hl = new HashMap<String,String>();
        while(initial<=len-1 && !(dinitial>=len-1)){
            if(!hm.isEmpty()){
                isPresent = hm.containsValue(strArr[initial]+"");
                if(!isPresent){
                    bm.append(strArr[initial]);
                    hm.put(strArr[initial]+"",strArr[initial]+"");
                    if(initial==len-1){
                        System.out.println("Longest substring is::" + bm);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(isPresent){
                    System.out.println("Longest substring is::" + bm);
                    bm.delete(0, bm.length());
                    ++dinitial;
                    initial--;
                    hm.clear();
                }
                initial++;
            }
            else
            {
                    bm.append(strArr[initial]);
                    hm.put(strArr[initial]+"",strArr[initial]+"");
                    initial++;
            }
        }
        hm.clear();
    }
```