# Finding longest repeated substring

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the longest repeated substring of given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212180/how-to-find-the-longest-repeated-substring-of-given-string)

I am suppose to find the longest repeated substring of a string.

```
    /**
This method will find the longest substring of a given string.
String given here is reassuring. 

 */
public String longestRepeatedSubstring()
{
    String longestRepeatedSubstring = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++ )
    {
        String one = text.substring(0,i); 

        for(int o = 0; o<text.length();o++)
        {
            Sting two = text.substring(0,o);
            if(one.equals(two))
            {
                longestRepeatedSubstring = one;
            }

        }

    }
    return longestRepeatedSubstring; 
}
```

Comment: If your question does not get answered try to address the comments, do not post it again.

Comment: i cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. I am trying to find the longest substring of a string.

Comment: I don't see any question mark on your post ;) Where's the actual question?

Comment: And did you try to use you debugger to debug it?

Comment: Your method returns the whole String, is that right?

Comment: no i am saving when it finds string that equal to String two. and string one will be always bigger than before so it would not contradict with result

Comment: You are comparing each substring from the start with every substring from the start and you will get a match when `i == o`  The last, which happens to be the longest, is the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use regular expression. Here it is:

```
/(?=((.+)(?:.*?\2)+))/s
```